# which virtual re-declarations of the Derived class are correct?

Tags: c++

```
A. Base* Base::copy(Base*); 
   Base *Derived::copy(Derived*);

B. Base* Base::copy(Base*);
   Derived *Derived::copy(Base*);

C. ostream& Base::print(int,ostream&=cout);
   ostream& Derived::print(int,ostream&);

D. void Base::eval() const;
   void Derived::eval();
```

It seems like the correct answer is 'C', but I'm not really sure why. Do anyone know the reason?

EDIT:

That is, which has implemented Polymorphism correctly?

Comment: Homework? What is the programming problem you're having?

Comment: nope. I'm reading a programming book. And it has this one, I just can't understand this one pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the 4 options are overriding Base class functions.
As per the C++ standard the `virtual` keyword needs to be present for saying **overridding**.

Basically, all 4 of them are **Hiding** the base class implementations of the same named function.

This is **Function Hiding** *not* **Function Overridding**.

**Good Read:**

**[What's the meaning of, Warning: `Derived::f(char)` hides `Base::f(double)`?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9)**

EDIT:
Assuming that the the `virtual` keyword is present the answer is:
**B**

Note that **C** is a *legal* but it is *Not Correct* & OP asks for *Correct Polymorphism Implementation* So,
**C:** does **not qualify as Correct.**

An overridding function should have the same prototype as that of the function it overrides,note that overridding function is allowed to have **[co-variant return types](http://www.tolchz.net/?p=33)**.

Applying this rule,
`A:` gets disqualified because it takes different parameter as function argument.
`C:` gets disqualified because you **[should not change the default arguments](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/005.htm)** of functions you override.
`D:` gets disqualified because preceeding `const` on a function is not same as function without the `const`.

Comment: how about if add "virtual" keyword, then how do you explain this problem?

Comment: I don't understand why 'C' is an appropriate Polymorphism rather then just overriding.

Comment: @Nohappy: The answer is `B` and I have updated the relevant details of why.

Comment: @Als, I removed my upvote, because C is correct too. Well, depends on the definition of "correct". In any case, C triggers overriding, i.e. `b->print` with `Base * b` will "correctly" dispatch to `Derived::print`.

Comment: @Als: as for `C` Its a `should-not` or `bad practice` but its legal as mentioned in your link http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/005.htm

Comment: @avakar: No Worries on the imaginary point,but the correct answer is **B**.The OP stated `which has implemented Polymorphism correctly?`and not `legally` I think Herb Sutter's article aptly points out why.

Comment: @NeelBasu: Stating again OP stated in the Q `which has implemented Polymorphism correctly?` not `legally`. So only correct answer is **B.**

Comment: Hmm `correctness` is relative LOL Thanks. It remembered me what I learnt long ago. Thanks.

Comment: @Als: http://www.tolchz.net/?p=33 mentions same cv-qualification as or `less` cv-qualification . So What about option D ?

Comment: @NeelBasu, it's talking about cv-qualification of the return type.

Answer (score 1):

option A is Hiding cause `Base::copy` and `Derived::copy` is taking different Type of arguments. and with option D the Base one is `const` where as Derived one is `non-const` both dont have the same cv-qualifier . and option C is using the same signature. so c is proper overriding.

option C changes the default parameter on overridden function. which is mentioned as `bad-practice` `should-not` but `legal C++` in http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/005.htm

as of http://www.tolchz.net/?p=33 on Covariant Return Types B is also correct as pointed by @Als

Edit: assuming there is a `virtual` keyword which is not mentioned in the question

to correct option A it should be

```
Base* Base::copy(Base*); 
Base* Derived::copy(Base*);
```

to correct option D it should be

```
void Base::eval() const;
void Derived::eval() const;
```

or

```
void Base::eval();
void Derived::eval();
```

Comment: Ya I see. Return type is not a part of function signature. However Its a common practice That I keep it same as the Base Class

Comment: Ya Ya You are correct. I remember once I read this probabbly in C++ coding Standards or in Exceptional C++ I forgot. and missed. Thanks

Comment: @Als: on `Derived::g( int i = 10 )` It says `Yes, this is legal C++, and yes, the result is well-defined, and no, don't do it` as mentioned in http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/005.htm This is mathematically correct but Bad practice.

Comment: @NeelBasu, note however that you cannot change the return type as you please, it must be a descendant of the original return type.

Comment: @NeelBasu: I am afraid I do not agree and I have stated the reasons appropriately.